# Get a list of tuples from two lists depending on their value and index

Tags: python

```
date = ['21 Jul 2021', False, False, '18 Jul 2021', False, False, '15 Jul 2021', False, False, '12 Jul 2021', False, False, '09 Jul 2021', False, False, '07 Jul 2021', False, False, '04 Jul 2021']

teams = [False, 'Utah Jazz - Los Angeles Clippers', 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns', False, False, 'Phoenix Suns - Milwaukee Bucks', False, False, 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns']
```

I have these two lists and I would like to make a list of tuples **(date, teams)** where the teams value are the teams playing (not False) and the date value is; starting from the index of the value of teams, the first value to the left that corresponds to an actual date.

I guess there is an easier way to frame to problem, but I couldn't find it. The result should be:

```
date_teams = [('21 Jul 2021','Utah Jazz - Los Angeles Clippers'), ('21 Jul 2021', 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns'), ('15 Jul 2021', 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns') ... ]
```

Note: Can't get rid of the `False` statements as they order the lists (Two matches can take place the same day)

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: That's a terrible way to store that data. If you have control over the code that generates it you should definitely look at changing it instead of attempting to fiddle with the data as it is.

Comment: As DeepSpace asked, why are your data arranged this way in the first place? Do you have any control over that? If not, are the dates always in chunks of three? I.e., is it only ever possible for a max of three teams to play on the same day?

Comment: @DeepSpace I scraped the data, I'll look into a more efficient way to get/store the data.

Comment: @ddejohn More than three teams can play at the same date, I'll try to scrape the data differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to handle this kind of problem is to introduce an intermediate variable to hold the last valid date as you iterate through the list.

```
date = ['21 Jul 2021', False, False, '18 Jul 2021', False, False, '15 Jul 2021', False, False, '12 Jul 2021', False, False, '09 Jul 2021', False, False, '07 Jul 2021', False, False, '04 Jul 2021']

teams = [False, 'Utah Jazz - Los Angeles Clippers', 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns', False, False, 'Phoenix Suns - Milwaukee Bucks', False, False, 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns']

last_date = None
date_teams = []
for (d, t) in zip(date, teams):
    if d:
        last_date = d
    if t:
        date_teams.append((last_date, t))

# [('21 Jul 2021', 'Utah Jazz - Los Angeles Clippers'), ('21 Jul 2021', 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns'), ('18 Jul 2021', 'Phoenix Suns - Milwaukee Bucks'), ('15 Jul 2021', 'Milwaukee Bucks - Phoenix Suns')]
```

note that `date` has 19 elements while `teams` has only 9, and `zip()` will truncate the longer list in favor of the shorter list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works well. I didn't know about the concept of intermediate variables, if you have the time, could you explain how this code works?  I get that last_date keeps the previous valid date but I don't see how the code implements that. Also, in my previous attempts I had to transform the False statement to strings as it kept returning me that Booleans couldn't be iterated, but in this code it seems as d and t only takes the strings without explicitly asking to do so.